# Why object is leaked (Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

Can someone explain why the object reference has counter 1 at the end?

```
5   Malloc  +1  1   00:03.412.584   Control -[PaymillPaymentService createServiceRequestWith:and:]
6   Autorelease         00:03.412.596   Control -[PaymillPaymentService createServiceRequestWith:and:]
7   Retain  +1  2   00:03.412.608   libsystem_sim_blocks.dylib  _Block_object_assign
8   Retain  +1  3   00:03.412.620   Control -[DashboardViewController requestMainTransactionsList]
9   Release -1  2   00:03.506.116   UIKit   _UIApplicationHandleEvent
10  Release -1  1   00:04.104.252   Control -[DashboardViewController transactionListLoadingComplete:]
```

5,6) calling alloc / init (factory method), returning autorelease object to caller

```
- (ServiceRequest*)createServiceRequestWith:(NSString*)url and:(id)delegate
{
    NSURL *fullURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:fullURL] autorelease];
    [NSMutableURLRequest basicAuthForRequest:request  withUsername:[self accessToken] andPassword:@""];

    ServiceRequest *serviceRequest = [[ServiceRequest alloc]  initWithURLRequest:request forDelegate:delegate];

    return [serviceRequest autorelease];
}
```

7) Passing as parameter to block

```
__unsafe_unretained id blockRequest = serviceRequest;
[operation setCompletionBlock:^{
    [self handleTransactionListRequest:blockRequest];

}];
```

8) Keeping assigned to strong property

```
ServiceRequest* request = [[[AppController sharedController] currentService] retrieveTransactionListInto:transactionList usingInterval:timeInterval forDelegate:self];
request.tag = @"main";
self.currentMainRequest = request;
```

9) ??? (probably block release)

10) Release from property

```
 [currentMainRequest release];
```

As to my understanding, the first malloc remains unbalanced, but first malloc creates object, it is always +1 !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blocks retain objects that they reference.

```
7   Retain  +1  2   00:03.412.608   libsystem_sim_blocks.dylib  _Block_object_assign
```

Try using the `__block` keyword alongside the variable to prevent it from being retained by the block.

Comment: This is a good commment. Added __block but currently my object is being deallocated basically immediately despite other retains ... Investigating futher ...

Comment: Also I actually need this object in block, is it ok?

Comment: You were right, after I moved autorelease in other method, the object was properly deallocated. So basically in my original text, that 7) block retain was unbalanced. Thanks!